# Retrieve records using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve records from a table which having fields like `image_type` and `priority`.

like

```
property id image_type priority
1            1          1
1            0          1
1            1          2
1            0          2
1            0          3
```

I want to show records like all image type records come together & arranged according to priority order either `ASC` or `DESC`.

Comment: Can you show the output that you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   undefined_table_name
GROUP BY 
   image_type 
ORDER BY
   image_type ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT `property id`, `image_type`, `priority`
FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY `image_type`, `priority` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You want them ordered by `priority` (ASC) and then by `image_type` (DESC), so you'll do it like this:

```
SELECT `property id`, `image_type`, `priority`
FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY `priority`, `image_type` DESC
```